# Parse Error compiling Octave script on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I'm not sure what this error is in relation to (that's why I included Ubuntu in the title, I don't know if this is related to the error).

I have a simple Octave script to practice numerical integration that looks like:

```
function y = f(x)
     y = x.*sin(1./x) .* sqrt(abs(1-x));
endfunction 

[q, ier, nfun, err] = quad("f", 0, 3)
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
parse error near line 11 of file /home/ariel/Desktop/Ariel/Programming/Octave_Programming/SimpsonsRule.m

  syntax error

>>> This is GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10)
                                                               ^
```

I'm confused about this error as there is no line 11 in the code?

Please note: I'm very new at programming and trying to learn a few languages at once so forgive what is probably a very simple problem, I wasn't able to find a solution after searching online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors in the code. It looks like you're attempting to run it from an Emacs buffer; have you tried running it directly from the command line?  E.g., `octave SimpsonsRule.m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a common "Hello, World!" type of exercise; identical code and arguments [here](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/help-octave/conversations/topics/14855).

You'll get an "`ABNORMAL RETURN...`" statement because your lower limit (`x=0`) is in the denominator of an expression in your function (`...sin(1./x)...`).  Set the lower limit to something very small like `.001` or something as in link above to avoid the discontinuity.

Putting exactly that code (even without the `1;` as suggested by @Andy) in a file (call it anything you want; your file name seemed to be `SimpsonsRule.m`), then running it from the command line,

```
octave SimpsonsRule.m
```

Gives the output that @Andy reports.  Changing the function call to

```
quad("f", 0.001, 3)
```

yields

```
q =  1.9819
ier = 0
nfun =  3297
err =  2.8021e-08
```

You're almost there!

If you're interested in learning another language, take a look at the Fortran source that underpins the implementation of [Octave's `quad` function](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d0/df8/dqagp_8f_source.html)! I like Fortran, but I'm mostly kidding.

---

Edits:

You have options here.

1. If you are on the Octave command line, copy and paste exactly those lines into the command line all at once (`function ...` through `quad("f",0,3)`) and it will work.
2. Put exactly the same content (`function ...` through `quad("f",0,3)`) into a file of any name (e.g., `SimpsonsRule.m`) and invoke it from the shell (`bash` or whatever, not `octave` prompt) as `octave SimpsonsRule.m` and it will work.
3. Or the more complicated solution: put the function definition (only) in a file by itself, then call the function separately.  More on this below.

Octave (and MATLAB) has conventions about file names and functions.  Just like in other programming languages, Octave knows to search certain directories and certain file names to find a function that you call. When you call a function that Octave doesn't know (e.g., if you call `foo(1)`, it will search through a set of directories for a file name called `foo.m` (i.e., same name as function with `.m` extension).

So your function is called `f`.  Create a file called `f.m` and put exactly the function definition of f:

```
function y = f(x)
   y = x.*sin(1./x) .* sqrt(abs(1-x));
endfunction
```

Then start `octave` session from your shell (prompt represented by `$`),

```
$ octave
```

Then call your shiny new `f` function:

```
octave:1> f(2)
```

and Octave will report

```
ans =  0.95885
```

Now run the `quad` command, which calls your function `f`:

```
octave:2> [q, ier, nfun, err] = quad("f", 0.001, 1)
```

And see what it does!

Keep in mind that `f` is probably not a good function name -- it doesn't describe at all what the function does and is likely to collide with some other function, although it's not harmful in this case.

If you're serious about learning Octave, I'd recommend starting with some tutorials.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks... I just read through that quickly and I think what you're saying is that the .m file should have the same name as the function? In the .m file, should I include the `quad("f", 0.001, 3)` line?

Comment: You have several options: 1- all from Octave prompt, 2- everything in one file; 3- separate function definition into one file, then call it from another file.  I'll expand above...

Comment: @user3460758 -- edited above; make sense? All set? Too much info? :)

Comment: nope, I think it's making sense! I'll try it now but I think I understand. Thanks for the explanation and for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use GNU Octave from inside Emacs? This could lead some problems because the plots with fltk toolkit are redrawn from readline (which is disabled in Emacs mode).

Another point: If your script file is SimpsonsRule.m, it has to begin with the function declaration of SimpsonsRule or you add some dummy statement like 1;:

```
1;
function y = f(x)
     y = x.*sin(1./x) .* sqrt(abs(1-x));
endfunction 

[q, ier, nfun, err] = quad("f", 0, 3)
```

when running this script octave returns

```
octave:1> SimpsonsRule
 ABNORMAL RETURN FROM DQAGP
q =  1.9819
ier =  1
nfun =  5061
err =    1.1522e-07
```

and q looks fine for me

Comment: Ok, well you're getting the correct answer but I'm still getting that same error. I am running it from inside Octave. Why do you need the dummy statement?

Comment: Matlab and Octave do some trickery with file naming and function naming: it expects a function named `foo` to be in a file called `foo.m`, and the function declaration is generally *first* and *only* code in that file. Mostly convention, but a source for confusion if you don't follow that convention.  See [Octave docs on functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Defining-Functions.html) for more on that.

Comment: @user3460758 Do you have any clue why you are seeing "This is GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10)"? Do you use Emacs?

Comment: Yes I use emacs, but I am new at all of this so I don't understand where that's coming from.

Comment: Emacs is getting in your way right now.  Don't attempt to run the `octave` script within an Emacs buffer.  Run the script from your regular terminal or command prompt as `octave foo.m` or whatever.  More detail above.